# rails test rspec capybara have_css no matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I am struggling with a simple test

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Home page", :type => :feature do
 scenario "When a user visit it" do
  visit "/"
  expect(page).to have_css('article', count: 10) 
 end
end
```

in the view I have this code

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <article>
    <header> <%= article.title%> </header>
    <div class="content-summary"> <%= article.body %> </div>
  </article>
  <hr/>
<% end %>
```

when I run the test I get

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('article', count: 10)
   expected to find css "article" 10 times but there were no matches
```

I run the server and I can see that 10 article tags exist.

when I change the view to this

```
<% 10.times do %>
  <article>
    <header> </header>
    <div class="content-summary"> </div>
  </article>
  <hr/>
<% end %>
```

the test pass

Please help me

Comment: could you please show your whole test file?

Comment: @Slava.K I added the whole test file

Comment: there are no articles created in your test. You need to create some in a `before` block. When you run server it uses `development` database, and test suites uses `test` one

Comment: @Slava.K you are right. Please write it as an answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails have separate databases for each of the environment. Local server is run in `development` mode by default and, therefore, is connected to the `app_name_development` database. RSpec, however, run tests in `test` environment and uses `app_name_test` database. That is why articles you see when you run a server are not available in the RSpec test.

Tests require manual data setup. If you are using RSpec then, I assume, you have [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) installed as well. In this case test should probably look like this:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Home page", :type => :feature do
  let!(:articles) { create_list(:article, 10) }

  scenario "When a user visit it" do
    visit "/"
    expect(page).to have_css('article', count: 10) 
  end
end
```